# JTDS JDBC Driver on Android, Connection to Sybase

Tags: android, eclipse, jdbc, sybase, jtds

I have been trying to connect to a Sybase SQL Anywhere 11 database engine using the JTDS 1.3.1.jar driver running in an Android application.

I am using Eclipse as my IDE and have set my Java Virtual Machine as 1.7 not the standard 1.6 as I believe JTDS 1.3 will only run in that version.

In my code I keep getting a  "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" when trying to make the database connection.

I have checked the URL connection string however the code isn't even getting to that point.

I have checked that the relevent jar file is loaded in the Project Settings - Java Build Path , both in the Libraries section and that they are checked in the Order and Export, for Build Time.

I have had the jTDS 1.2 driver successfully connect and issue a select statement
however when I execute a query, it results in an error of a "TDS Protocol error: Invalid packet type 0x0", so there is an issue with the 1.2 driver Tabular data stream and Sybase 11.

I have also tried the native Sybase jdbc drivers "jconn2.jar & jconn3.jar" however these libraries reference some other classes "org.ietf.jgss.GSSManage" that don't appear to be supported in Android. So these libraries are not able to be used.

My Connection code is as follows;

```
/* Setup Driver Manager - Working JTDS*/
DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance());
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(60);
/* Build Connections Working JTDS URL */
URL = "jdbc:jtds:sybase://<ip>:<port>";
/* Set Up Properties */
prop = new Properties();
prop.put("user", "user");
prop.put("password", "pass");
prop.put("instance", "named instance");
prop.put("tds", "5.0");
prop.put("appName", "Android");

/* Attempt to connect to driver. */
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,prop);
```

Any ideas or other suitable drivers for android would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you think directly connecting to a database from an Android client would be a good idea? JDBC is designed for reliable connectivity to a server. Mobile devices do not have that.

Comment: Im trying to connect to an already existing enterprise database application to create a viewing front end for android bearing in mind it will only be used in a WiFi environment not over 3G.